# Official ADB drivers for mi a1

Tags: adb

I have tried everything to install google camera on my mi a1 but due to problem of ADB drivers it does not show my device in attached devices list after running "adb devices" command.I have tried everything but it doesn't show my device in that list.plz help me

Answer (score 0):

My solution in the end: install HiSuite !!!! 
I have had problems installing the ADB driver for my XIAOMI Mi A1.  At one point, the mobile device appeared in the PC device manager but did'nt have any driver.
I tried intalling the Mi PC suite but it coudn't access the device, asking to update the driver.
As suggested in the post mentionned below, I installed the HiSuite.  Unexpectidly, it solved my problem. ADB is working now. Besides, HiSuite works as a PC suite for the Mi A1 and even allows now to sync with Outlook.

(see Google:  techubber blogspot com 2017 02 mi-pc-suite-and-usb-connection-problems-device-not-connected )